# How I count duplicate symbol in each record

Tags: sql

If i want to count (x) in each row in my db(have 10,000 rows) that shown it below

```
    data 
@ REAMS  X PALLETSDIMENSION (WXLXH) :    " X   " X  "
@ 160 REAMS x 40 PALLETS1 CARTON = 5 REAMS
@ 5 REAMS x 15,360 CARTONSDIMENSION (WXLXH): 9"x13"x13"
```

and I want the result in count  is

```
     data                                                        count x
@ REAMS  X PALLETSDIMENSION (WXLXH) :    " X   " X  "                5
@ 160 REAMS x 40 PALLETS1 CARTON = 5 REAMS                           1
@ 5 REAMS x 15,360 CARTONSDIMENSION (WXLXH): 9"x13"x13"              5
```

Is there anyway  how to write code for get count number of x?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: How do you get "3" for the first and last row?  I count four "x"s in both strings.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of a particular letter in a string by using a difference of string lengths:

```
select length(data) - length(replace(lower(data), 'x', '')) as num_xs
```

However, this would return "4" for the first and last row, not 3.  So, I'm not sure what calculation you really want.

Note:  In some databases, `length()` is spelled `len()`.

Comment: Gordon: Careful, what if he only wants to count upper case X?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Then the second and third rows wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @temp AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '@ 5 REAMS x 15,360 CARTONSDIMENSION (WXLXH): 9"x13"x13"'
    ,@occuranceCountForCharacter CHAR(1) = 'X'

SELECT LEN(@temp) - LEN(REPLACE(@temp, @occuranceCountForCharacter, '')) AS CharCount
```